# Using Gmail Java API to change the default signature in Gmail

Tags: java, api, gmail, signature

in the meantime Gmail supports multiple signatures for one mailadress. I am using the Gmail Java API to set a signature. Using the function setSignature("Text") it is possible to set a signature.
Documentation see here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/
Now, since I can set several signatures, it would be great to set a specific signature as default. Same as you can do in the gmail user interface.
In the documentation I cannot find anything how to set a signature as default.

Maybe someone here has an idea how this could work or if there is any function implemented which is not added to the documentation.

I appreciate any help.

BR

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in this can you send the code for this to me on github my name is [List https://github.com/Wrightgo](https://List%20https://github.com/Wrightgo) I am not very good at java I just like it but to my untrand eye I would do the following:

```
SendAs primaryAlias = null;
SendAsResponse aliases = gmailService.users().settings().sendAs().list("me").execute();
for (SendAs alias: aliases.getSendAs()) {
    if (alias.getIsPrimary()) {
        primaryAlias = alias;
        break;
    }
}
SendAs aliasSettings = new SendAs().setSignature("I heart cats.");
SendAs result = gmailService.users().settings().sendAs().patch(
        "me",
        primaryAlias.getSendAsEmail(),
        aliasSettings)
        .execute();
System.out.println("Updated signature for " + result.getDisplayName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea thats the code from the documentation. This is to set a signature and it is working.
But in the meantime google allows to set more signatures and to choose which signature is the default one (see attachment).
[image]